# FFMPEG split video is not working properly

Tags: ffmpeg, split

I am trying to split video then into frames. I am passing starting time and ending time dynamically.

for ex:

```
ffmpeg -i /Users/mypc/Documents/Avatar/input.mp4 -ss 00:00:39.799 -t 00:00:42.039  /Users/mypc/Downloads/testing/output.mp4
```

It should cut the video from 39th second to 42 second. Approximately 3 seconds. But, it's splitting more than 3 seconds. I am stuck why it's behaving like that.

Am i missing something in my command or anything?

Please suggest

Screen shot of my terminal attached :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm playing with wrong command. -t will indicating the video will split upto -t from -ss.

Correct command is

```
 ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:01:00 -to 00:02:00 -c copy output.mp4
```